# Calling @afterThrowing advice from catch block for printing thrown exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, log4j, spring-aop

We are using Spring AOP with Log4j for logging in our application. I have implemented @Before, @After, @AfterThrowing advice in the application. But I am facing following issue :

When any exception gets caught in catch block then it does not invoke @AfterThrowing advice for printing error stack trace.

```
public void create() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex)
    {
        // want to call any advice for printing ex.printStackTrace();           
    }

}
```

I want to print "error stack trace" for the exception caught in catch block. Means whenever any exception occurs in try block and caught by catch then some advice should get called for printing error details.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP can only intercept method executions, so if you catch the exception in the method it won't reach the interceptor. You can advise exceptions being thrown in AspectJ, I believe (using the `handler()` pointcut designator).

Comment: How about accepting an answer then? At least an up vote?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Spring AOP works only at method invocation level. In other words, the join points for advice are method calls.

As the name suggests, `@AfterThrowing`, can execute after a method throws something. In your case, the method doesn't throw anything from the advice's perspective, ie. the method doesn't terminate by throwing an exception. It ends normally because the exception is caught and handled.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with spring AOP. According to your source,

```
public void create() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex)
    {
        // want to call any advice for printing ex.printStackTrace();           
    }

}
```

dont put `try{}catch()` inside this method. Then your Aspect advice will trigger. And also put the try catch statement to the method caller. like this.

```
class Abc{
public void create() throws Exception
{
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
}
```

then,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        abc_obj.abc();
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        System.out.println("NUllpointer");
    }
}
```